# Optimal Way to Handle Bulk Processing

Tags: php

So the is the following query that I am currently processing

```
$users = $curl->request('GET_USERS'); // Makes an external call and returns an Array of Users (Avg 600+). The response size of the json object is around 380 kB
foreach($users as $user){
    // Fetch User Information 
    $user_info = $curl->request('GET_USER_INFO'); // Response Size of the jSON Object is 21.54 kB
    // Update External Service with this Info
    $external_service = $curl->request('UPDATE_USER',$user_info);
} // Loop will happen for around 600+ iterations on average.
```

So is my approach to this ok or is there a better way to handle this ?

Comment: It depends entirely on the API's limitations, what you're intending to do with the data, and the number of users you're getting info for. Having said that, making a CURL request inside of a loop is generally not a good idea. And when looping over `600+` of them, you'll almost definitely be capping out an API's limits. Why do you need to update 600 users at once? Does the API not have a better method for this?

Comment: @ObsidianAge well there's actually no way else but using an external API to fetch and update. So, in that case, would there be any alternative solution than the above code?

Comment: @ObsidianAge oh and this external API is sort of like an Internal Application API we use to communicate.

Comment: There's too little information here to write a good answer. Obsidian Age tried to find an opening but you shut it down firmly.

Comment: The optimal solution is making a non-blocking language responsible for this kind of task. With PHP it wouldn't be optimal at all.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Ya, if it was in my hand I wouldn't be doing this approach at all.